# PHP sessions in Apache

Tags: php, apache, session

I am running a PHP application on an apache server. Where can I find the session files that the server creates? is there a standard file name for php sessions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally they are stored under `/tmp`. You can also check `session.save_path` in the `php.ini`  (or use `phpinfo();`) for more details.

Sometimes they are also stored in a database. You might want to check if `session.save_handler` is set to `files`.